# The right way to check whether mysqli query was successful

Tags: php, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've read several articles about the problem like this however none of them helped me and I am a bit confused what to do.

Basically, I want to check whether the sql query performed without any errors. To do that, do I have to use both of the `if` statements shown below?

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table VALUES (?, ?, ?);"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $a, $b, $c);

    if(!$stmt->execute())
    {
        // Do I have to catch the problem here?
    }

    if($stmt->affected_rows === -1){
       // Do I have to catch the problem here?
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
else
{
    // Do I need to catch the problem here?
}
```

Comment: *Why* do you want to check the result? What you're going to do with it?

Comment: I just have to know if data were saved (In this case), if not because something happened I need to know that and notify user about this problem...

Comment: What if your problem is not with mysqli but - say - with memory? Gonna write another notifier? What about filesystem errors, division by zero, missing variable?

Comment: Probably no ,but one thing is missing var, division by zero and other when user is going to lost data... *Of course if we are talking for example about calculator I will write notifier for division by zero... Same with other things...

Comment: You don't understand. Division by zero will cause the same data lost as mysql failure. You have to handle ALL errors the same way, not only ones you are aware of.

Comment: That's my question - If I have to catch all those possible errors because there is hundreds of examples that ignore this so I have been completely confused. Now I know, thanks

Comment: You don't need to catch anything. PHP will do it for you and in case of error will send 500 HTTP status. You can check it in your AJAX code and show error message to user. Nothing mysqli specific is required. - you only have to make mysqli raise errors like shown in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check the return values of `prepare()`, `bind_param()` and `execute()`. They all return `false` if they fail.

If `execute()` does not return `false` then the `INSERT` should have gone through successfully, and therefore checking `affected_rows` only makes sense if you want to know *how many rows* were affected.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Put this line above mysqli connect. This is all you need.

To notify a user on problems, check response status of AJAX request. if it's 500 - then there was a problem with save.

Comment: Thanks ,but I have one more question. What if this is not enough for me and I want to make some report, I mean for instance send mail to my self about particular error. Which option is best in this case?

Comment: Can you please provide a *real* case? So I'll be able to tell you most suitable option. Sending email in case of one particular mysql error seems too artificial case to me.

Comment: If happened error in some block (That currently holds comment as you can see above) I want to send from that place for example email or do redirect to another web site. Now I am thinking what is the best way to do it. Do I have to catch all those possible errors in those places or use try{}catch(){}?

Comment: Iour idea of handling exceptions is wrong. For some reason you insists on most inconvenient and unreliable way. And you don't even have a practical case to prove your ideas. But I am not going to support bad practices, so, please don't ask me.

Comment: To be more precise if I want to do something like this http://pastebin.com/Kygcm5Hv (It doesn't have to be specifically sending mail, it can be something absolutely different). Is it alright do that in every mysql query? mysql_report() is alright for AJAX ,but what if mysql_report() is not inadequate for other...

Comment: @0101 we are going circles. For some reason you don't want to handle all the errors the same way, and refuse to handle them properly. mysql_report() is the best error handler you can get. But only if you know what are you doing. If you want your mailbox spammed with thousands mails due to 5 minute db downtime - you are welcome. But please don't ask me to join the mess.

Comment: As I said above sending mails is just EXAMPLE. Never mind, anyway thank you for your time and help.

Comment: The problem is that *every* your example taken out of nowhere contains such a pitfall. That's why when you have a certain scenario in mind, you are welcome to come and ask for the right way